# Is possible to replace a token inside a view field?

Tags: views, tokens

I'm on D10.1.x.

I need to add a `current-user:xx` token inside a column of a view.

I've seen that by default, the token replacement doesn't work, e.g. if I use `[current-user:mail`, the token is not replaced.

I've tried the [workaround described here](https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1417266#comment-14294909), however it doesn't work, as I get the error:

> Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unknown "drupal_token" tag in "__string_template__d63e10f79d9d43968f5ae212f85498f7" at line 1. in Twig\Parser->subparse() (line 160 of /var/www/html/vendor/twig/twig/src/Parser.php).

Any idea\suggestion on how I could implement that, or how implement this workaround? Thanks.

Comment: Tested D10.2.1 and twig_tweak 3.2.1. drupal_token works, with a token for the site name and the current user mail. Please try this on a fresh install and provide more info how to reproduce the error. If you get it working you still have a problem with caching, a views field is usually not cached by user.

Comment: @4uk4 sorry for the late reply, but I had no time to check this again. At the time of your comment I too just tried with a clean D10 install and saw it worked. However, I don't know why, but after the last core updates - currently the site is on 10.1.8 - I can't replicate anymore the error. Aka, I can place a token inside a view field using twig tweak `drupal_token` function. Thanks for the check nevertheless.